# How to group mails by sender and sort them by the time received by sender in mutt

Tags: email, sort, mutt

How to group mails by sender and sort them by the time received by sender in `mutt`?

I have tried the following:

```
set sort = sender  
set sort_aux = date-received
```

- Are there any tips?
- Am I setting the type wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
set sort = from
set sort_aux = date-received
```

in my muttrc, there is sorting option `from`.